# How to combine HTML Export files with Vue.js App?

Tags: html, vue.js, documentation-generation

I have a Vue.js app that I want to host using Netlify for example. Besides content from different headless content management systems, I have HTML pages (documentation) from other sources, which I also want to display in the Vue.js app as documentation.

Do you know best practices on how I can include static HTML pages in a Vue.js and build a navigation for the documentation?

Should I place the HTML pages in the project and load them via HTML Loader? Is this possible in a dynamic way?

```
npm install html-loader --save-dev

module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: config => {
    config.module
      .rule('html')
      .test(/\.html$/)
      .use('html-loader')
      .loader('html-loader')
  }
};

import html from '@/documentation/app/content.html' // how to load dynamic?

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      html...
    }
  }
}
```

I have packed the HTML files of a documentation into a folder. Since there are several documentations, I have several folders.

Then I created a Vue.js app and imported the HTML loader. I can load single HTML files. But I don't know how to dynamically load HTML files by parameter. And how I can best build and store the hierarchy (navigation). Per .json file?

Comment: you can dynamically load it via the dynamic import using `import('@/documentation/app/content.html').then((content) => {})` or `const html = await import('@/documentation/app/content.html')` inside an async function

Comment: Is there a best practice when you have a lot of documentation (300+) with 200+ pages each? Each documentation also has 3-5 public versions. Does it make sense to continue to store the documentation as HTML export, so that the loading time is also fast? Or is it better to import the HTML files into a CMS?